# proper way to iterate over a C++ std::map doesn't work

Tags: c++, xml, stl, stdmap, abstract-syntax-tree

So I have an abstract syntax tree of Node objects. Each Node has any number children nodes as well as any number of tags which are tidbits of information that are attached to the Node via a std::map structure. Now I want to print the the entire syntax tree in XML-like format. To this end I use this function:

```
int __ostreamNode_indent = 0;
std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream & ss, Node* n )
{   
    for( int i = 0 ; i < __ostreamNode_indent ; ++i )
        ss << "  ";

    ss << "<" << n->getSymbolType() << " ";
    for( std::map<std::string,std::string>::iterator itr = n->getTags().begin() ; itr != n->getTags().end() ; ++itr )
    {   
        ss << itr->first << "=\"" << itr->second << "\" ";
    }
    ss << "numtags=" << n->getTags().size() << " ";

    if( n->getChildren().size() == 0 )
        ss << "/";

    ss << ">" << std::endl;

    __ostreamNode_indent++;
    for( unsigned int i = 0 ; i != n->getChildren().size() ; ++i )
    {   
        ss <<  n->getChildren().at(i);
    }
    __ostreamNode_indent--;

    if( n->getChildren().size() != 0 )
    {
        for( int i = 0 ; i < __ostreamNode_indent ; ++i )
            ss << "  ";

        ss << "</" << n->getSymbolType() << ">" << std::endl;
    }

    return ss;
}
```

The structure is precisely the way I want it: the XML-tag type is the node's type and the node's tags are embedded in the same XML opening tag. The children nodes are placed between the opening and closing tags. Here is an example:

```
<block line="0" numtags=2 >
  <funcdef line="0" numtags=2 >
    <identifier line="0" col="13" value="main" numtags=3 />
    <expressionunion line="0" numtags=2 >
      <identifier line="0" col="16" value="a" numtags=3 />
      <identifier line="0" col="19" value="b" numtags=3 />
    </expressionunion>
    <assignment line="1" numtags=2 >
      <identifier line="1" col="5" value="c" numtags=3 />
      <numel line="1" numtags=2 >
        <solveunder line="1" numtags=2 >
          <identifier line="1" col="11" value="a" numtags=3 />
          <identifier line="1" col="16" value="b" numtags=3 />
        </solveunder>
      </numel>
    </assignment>
    <return line="2" numtags=2 >
      <power line="2" numtags=2 >
        <identifier line="2" col="12" value="c" numtags=3 />
        <identifier line="2" col="14" value="b" numtags=3 />
      </power>
    </return>
  </funcdef>
</block>
```

This example also demonstrates the problem. I iterate over all tags with the lines

```
    for( std::map<std::string,std::string>::iterator itr = n->getTags().begin() ; itr != n->getTags().end() ; ++itr )
    {   
        ss << itr->first << "=\"" << itr->second << "\" ";
    }
```

and output them as key="value". However, sometimes this loop skips the last element. Notice how the line immediately following this loop outputs the number of tags. When there are two tags present, only the first is actually shown. Why isn't the second one being shown?

EDIT: Mark B answered the question; read his answer for the exact explanation of what went wrong. He psychically guessed that this was the definition of getTags():

```
std::map<std::string,std::string> getTags()
{   
    return tags;
};
```

Changing it to this (adding the ampersand) did the trick:

```
std::map<std::string,std::string> & getTags()
{   
    return tags;
};
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but `__ostreamNode_indent` is a name reserved for the implementation.  Any name that contains double-underscore is reserved, regardless of scope.

Comment: What is the declaration for `getTags()`  Is it a reference to the map, or something else?

Comment: Would suggest using `const_iterator` rather than `iterator` since you're not changing anything, but I don't think it will solve your problem.

Comment: The code does not look as if there's a problem with it. Maybe you should provide a [SSCCE](sscce.org). Have you tried to debug the problem? Maybe you also want to use references instead of calling `getChildren()` and `getTags()` again and again - it's more performant and sometimes more readable as well. An oh, `__ostreamNode_indent` is a reserved identifier, don't use double underscores in your own C++ identifiers, those are reserved for the "implementation" (meaning preprocessor, compiler, standard library implementation etc.)

Comment: Post declaration of `Node::getTags()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to use my psychic debugging skills and suggest that `getTags()` is returning a container by value (rather than a reference to the actual container), so the `begin` and `end` nodes refer to different temporary containers. At that point whatever happens to the iteration is fair game since the original temporary container is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Mark is probably right.

Another possibility is you corrupted that map.  Say by editing a key after it is in the map.